# Why i cannot see on my fig , a specific color for outliers?

Tags: python, plotly, data-science

i created an api using django
for visualisation i used plotly
How i can modify my code to see on my fig , outliers in one color : red?

```
 plt.plot(df_abs.loc[outlier].iloc[1:], markerfacecolor='red')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your loop, and check if it works

```
 plt.plot(df_abs.loc[outlier].iloc[1:], markerfacecolor='red')
```

for more details check [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)